# How can I use Google Maps in Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.ios, google-maps-markers

I want to use Google Maps in my Xamarin.iOS project, I couldn't find any package in NuGet store that could help to implement Google Maps in my project.

I want to get my current location and show customized pins on locations that I get from the server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nuget package [Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps/) is a Xamarin.iOS binding library for "Google Maps SDK for iOS".

`PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps -Version 2.1.0.2`

Google's Maps SDK for iOS documentation:

Re: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/

C# Source with samples:

Re: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/tree/master/source/Google/Maps

Comment: The samples link is 404, could you update it? Here it is though: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/tree/master/source/Google/Maps