# Support GoogleMaps for native iOS in .net7?

Tags: xamarin, maui, .net-7.0, maui-ios, .net-ios

Orginally a Xamarin project (Xamarin-ios, Xamarin-Android) was migrated to .net6 according to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects).

Most of the dependencies was kept since iOS and Android still had a different codebase and .net6+ supported monoandroid([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects#update-dependencies)). Since the next step was updating to .net7 there was some issues specifically with iOS Google Maps in these NuGets packages:

- Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps:6.0.1.1
- Xamarin.Build.Download:0.11.4

The issues are:

- The above NuGets only have support for xamarinios10 and net6.0-ios15.4, e.g. is officially incompatible with .net7-ios.
- All the documentation for .net7 apps only mention multi-project .NET MAUI app, and not how to solve it natively with only MauiEssentials (previously XamarinEssentials) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548516/how-can-i-use-google-maps-in-xamarin-ios-project).

The questions are as following:

1. Can this be solved by using only MauiEssentials, and if so how?
2. Are they any other binding libs for .net7-ios GoogleMaps?
3. What are the risks for running an "incompatible" NuGet packet since it works currently?
4. Is the future dead for developing in .net7-ios/android and above?

Answer (score 0):

1.No.

2.You can use [Maui.GoogleMaps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Onion.Maui.GoogleMaps/#supportedframeworks-body-tab), it's targeting .NET 7 for best experience. Get your API Keys from Google and configure for iOS as below:

```
using Maui.GoogleMaps.Hosting;
...
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>();
            
#if ANDROID
        builder.UseGoogleMaps();
#elif IOS
        builder.UseGoogleMaps(Variables.GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY);
#endif
        return builder.Build(); 
}
```

3. I would suggest that make sure there aren't any dependences on any Xamarin native package. For instance Xamarin.Essentials and so on.
4. You can refer to the [Roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Roadmap) and see this:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/10839

Comment: To clarify my post: We do NOT have a MauiApp, only .net-ios and .net-android.

Comment: @TurnOffNFC Thanks for the update, for the native .net-ios and native .net-android, I don't think there's any other binding libs, you can search in this site:https://www.nuget.org/packages